# Centering text in odt files

Tags: php, text, odt, odf

I'm using odt file as a template for my transcripts and I'm using php to insert the transcript in the odt file which then outputs a correctly formated odt file but there is some text that I want to center horizontally for which I've written this code

```php
$transcript .= "<text:p text:style-name=\"CenterText\">Proceedings</text:p>";
```

from liber office I have added a paragraph style called CenterText and I have set the alignment to center to make it work but for some reason the text `proceedings` is not even being rendered.

can somebody please tell me what might be wrong and how I can fix the issue

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to create documents by hand, you're going to have a bad time. Use [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to easily create .odt files. There you can use

`$PHPWord->addParagraphStyle('CenterText', array('align'=>'both')`

`$section->addText($text, 'CenterText');`

to center your text.

Comment: I Can't use PHPWord since it will require php version 7 and I'm on version 5 also I can't update my php version since it will break a lot of things so is there any other way to do it

Comment: @Tarun Do you have PHP 5.3.3 or higher? You can use an [older version](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/releases/tag/0.18.3) that's compatible. For Composer, use `composer require phpoffice/phpword:0.18.3`

Comment: `Composer 2.3.0 dropped support for PHP <7.2.5 and you are running 5.6.40-65+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, please upgrade PHP or use Composer 2.2 LTS via "composer self-update --2.2". Aborting.`

this is the error I get after running the command that you gave me

(I'm using version 5.6.40)

Comment: Like they said, try Composer 2.2. `composer self-update --2.2`

Comment: I already tried it but it gives me the same error

Comment: You should update your PHP then. You probably don't want to hear it, but if you don't it's gonna bite you in the a** someday. 5.3.3 is ancient, it's 13 years old already.

Comment: Thanks for the help Chix I'll talk with my team and see if they are ok with updating the php version

Comment: @Tarun At the very least, you should move to [7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php). It's a good tradeoff between compatibility with newer plugins and your existing codebase. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732360/upgrade-php-version-in-project-from-5-6-to-8-1